# error in 'rosmake rivz'

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rviz']                                    
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/pyb/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130427-141253
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rviz'] to:
['rviz']                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61646/error-in-%27rosmake-rivz%27/) by [rockelin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4773/rockelin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This doesn't appear to have any errors.  And it looks like you are using prebuilt packages with ROS_NOBUILD flags in the packages which means that you do not need to compile the packages with rosmake.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0